# What is the best way to ensure correct indentation when a quotation begins with a quotation?

Tags: indentation, best-practices, quoting, nesting

It is sometimes necessary (I have just discovered) to typeset a block quotation which itself begins with a block quotation. When this happens, however, the indentation of the first paragraph of the nested quotation is incorrect. (It seems to be twice what it should be.)

[image: incorrect]

In contrast, if the nested block quotation does not begin the outer quotation, the indentation is correct.

[image: correct]

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  \begin{quotation}
    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.

    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
  \end{quotation}
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

What is the best way to ensure correct indentation in such cases?

Comment: `\noindent` works but can't be the best way...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd really like LaTeX to figure it out so I don't need to remember to compensate each time ;).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I also need `\unskip`, I guess. ?

Answer (score 4):

You can throw away any pending item label before the quotation. If you need `quotation` also to work as first thing in a real `\item` you might want to check what list you are in, but this works here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\oldquotation\quotation
\def\quotation{\setbox\@labels\hbox{}\oldquotation}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  \begin{quotation}
      As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.

    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
  \end{quotation}
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I need `\unskip`, too? Is that the right way to avoid additional vertical space?

Comment: @cfr you can't unskip on the main vertical list. Is there extra vertical space? I wouldn't expect any I think, although your MWE wasn't so good for visualising vertical spacing:-)

Answer (score 1):

This might cause other problems, but so far so good.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldquotation=\quotation
\renewcommand{\quotation}{\oldquotation\leavevmode}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotation}
  \begin{quotation}
    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.

    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
  \end{quotation}% if you want the next line indented, add a blank line or \par
  As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: doing it that way forces an extra white paragraph and a vertical skip before both quotations: use `X` instead of `\leavevmode` and you'll see.